# Codeigniter: How can I redirect to home when user click on back button after logout?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and my question is same [How can I redirect to home when user click on back button after logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194566/how-can-i-redirect-to-home-when-user-click-on-back-button-after-logout)

I tried below code in `views/header.php` and also in **controller top** but nothing progress..!

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

I also tried

```
  /* @author: Muhammad Sajid
   * @name: do_logout
   */
    public function do_logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->clearCache();
        redirect("login/index/0");
    }

    //+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
    //@ http://jsfromhell.com
    public function clearCache(){
        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
    }
```

but not found solution....

Comment: Why are you worried about this issue? cos if you have made your controllers login protected the page (after clicking back button) will disappear (assuming you redirect to login page if not logged in) as soon as user refreshes the page if you know what I mean..

Comment: use redirect('','your location'); insted of redirect("login/index/0"); in route,
or http://stackoverflow.com/a/2267257/1568236
user base_url

Answer (score 0):

can you plz specify... more since the back button will just take you to the previous page which may or may not be the home page...
a simple way to redirect the user can be

> redirect(http://localhost/.....the desired url);

I once had a problem that i wanted to re-direct the user to the previous page after he loged in however the problem was that the previous page was a log in form and not the page the user used for comming to log in form

Solution i added the desired page address to session by

> $this->session->set_userdata('redirect', current_url());

and then after log in redirected the user by

> $redirect = $this->session->userdata('redirect');
>      redirect($redirect);

Comment: Please first understand my problem, i m not asking about redirection after login. I talked about after logout user could not go back to previous screen using browser BACK button.

Answer (score 0):

This issue would most likely be solved with javascript since php isn't executed upon using the Back-button.

Either run an ajax on each page load that simply checks if you're logged in, and redirect accordingly if not.

Or you could maybe do like this when clicking the logout-button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('http://example.com/do_logout');
    self.close();
</script>
```

I'm not fully sure if all browsers support it, but in theory that would open a new tab, close current and therefor remove the possibility to "Back".

Answer (score 0):

You can control cache with meta tags use following:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

for detailed information visit this link:
http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me nicely!!!

```
<?php
   if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class admin extends CI_Controller
   {
      public function __construct()
      {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->no_cache();
      }

      protected function no_cache()
      {
          header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
          header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
          header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
      }
   }
```